# iPhone: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key alarmsViews

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I've been banging my head with this error for the last 5 hours. I have done all the googling I could yet none of the solutions seem to work for me so I will explain my particular situation and see if you guys can pick out what my issue is.

My main UI is a View with 6 Views inside of it. Each view contains an image and a label inside of it. Am I allowed to do this to contain objects together?

Anyways, I erased all my connection one by one from the File Owner and started over again. I pressed ctrl and dragged the mouse over to the main view to attach it to my view. Ran the project: great, no errors.

Connected one of the sub views, bam! Error pops up right away.

My File Owner's custom class is set to my UIViewController class.

I have the IBOutlets defined properly in the header, and synthesized in the implementation.

Let me know what you need to help me out.

** EDIT **

I set a breakpoint and found the line marked with --> <-- to be the culprit:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View_main" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

--> [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; <--

    return YES;
}
```

And the error thrown by the compiler is:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x6c6a0d0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key myView.'
```

All help welcomed!

Comment: Could you show error description?

Answer (score 2):

check this link [you'll find the answer here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1)

> The error “this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key XXX” usually occurs when loading a nib that refers to a property that doesn’t actually exist. This usually happens when you remove an outlet property from your code but not from the connections in the nib.

Comment: Thanks for the link! This is extremely helpful! Will edit my original post with more info.

Comment: do you have IBOutlet myView and is it connected to the respective element in xib file?

Comment: Yes myView is defined in the header and synthesized as well as connected to the File Owner object in the xib file.

Comment: in section "Referencing Outlets"?

Comment: No it's in section Outlets only

Comment: Oh sorry I guess if I select the sub views themselves they each have a connection to File's Owner under Referencing Outlets

Comment: Check Referencing Outlets section in your xib. i'm pretty sure the cause of the crash is there. There's probably a xib element referring to a variable which doesn't exist in your .h file

Comment: I copied the design elements from the .xib, deleted the .xib and created a new .xib with a matching name to the class and reconnected the main view and one of the sub views so that no other connections could exist and it is still throwing the error.

Comment: it's hard to tell what's going on. the only advice i may give you now is not to use xib files. make all the interface in code. it's not difficult at all

Comment: I think I might just do that. Screw IB.

Answer (score 2):

> My File Owner's custom class is set to my UIViewController class.

This is ambiguous, and clashes with:

```
self.viewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"View_main" bundle:nil];
```

You are using a "vanilla" UIViewController rather than your custom subclass (whose class name you haven't mentioned). When the nib is loaded and it attempts to connect your outlets, they do not exist, so the exception is raised. Change the alloc/init to use your UIViewController subclass:

```
#import "View_main.h"

...

self.viewController = [[View_main alloc] initWithNibName:@"View_main" bundle:nil];
```

And ensure that the custom class of your view controller is set to View_main in the nib as well.

Comment: The name of my view controller class is View_main. Do I import the View_main.h at the top of my app delegate file to make this work?

Comment: Now I get all windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch.

Comment: @interface AppDelegate : UI Responder <UIApplicationDelegate>
{
    IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
    IBOutlet UIViewController *viewController;
}

//@property (nonatomic, retain) UIWindow *window;
//@property (strong, nonatomic, retain) UIViewController *viewController;

Comment: Hey man sorry kept hitting enter and had to edit multiple times.

Comment: I also have "//@class View_main;" above //@interface (Have to double slash before the at signs, apparently it thinks I'm trying to notify stackoverflow users in my comments)

Comment: This is getting a bit confusing now. You will have to put a breakpoint in your didFinishLaunching and check that the window and view controller are created properly.